# Get executing action in HttpModule

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a HttpModule and need to know which action is executing. And I need to get the MethodInfo from the method, the action name is not enough, I need the real method from the type.

I know how to get the controller and action:

```
string controllerName = ...RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
string actionName = ...RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
```

I want to do:
    `controllerType.GetMethod(actionName)`

This will of course result in AmbiguousMatchException...

Which signature is executing? Is it possible to know?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?  In 4.0 and above, routing is built into ASP.NET (not just MVC), so in your module you can use HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData, and get the action value from there.  To figure out what method is executing, you'd then use the rest of the route data, i.e. anything that's not the controller, action, or area, as these would match the parameters on your action method.

Comment: I'm using HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData. But I can't get the correct overload for the action? Do you know how to do that?

Comment: See my suggested answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  It loops through the route data and gets all the pieces of the route data that aren't well known, i.e. controller, action, and area.  This is assuming you're using the default route.  Every other part of the route, whether it's in the URL or query string, will map to a method parameter.  You can get the Type of these route values and use them to get the specified Method info.

```
List<Type> methodParams = new List<Type>();
string action = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData["action"];
foreach (var data in HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values)
{
    if ((data.Key != "action") && (data.Key != "controller") && (data.Key != "area"))
        methodParams.Add(data.Value.GetType());                
}

Type t; //assume this is your type that implements the action method you're interested in.  
        //I'm assuming you know it somehow

MethodInfo info = t.GetMethod(action, methodParams.ToArray());
```

Comment: I've tried it but I just get 3 Keys in the RouteData, controller, action and id. And event though the action have 2 parameters, I can't find them in the RouteData.

Comment: Are there multiple action methods with the same name that just vary by parameters? What does your action method signature and URL look like?

Comment: Example:
1:
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult Report()
2:
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public virtual JsonResult Report(ViewModel viewModel)

Comment: Can you post an example URL?

Comment: If that's your URL, nothing in just the URL itself is going to help you determine what action method is being accessed.  I was assuming (incorrectly) that you had more route data in the form of query strings, etc.  So you can easily get the action now.  Are all your actions just an HTTP Get vs Http Post difference?  If so then you can use Request.HttpMethod to get the HttpMethod, and use reflection to look at the attributes of all methods that match your action name, and pick the one based on if it is decorated with HttpGet or HttpPost attributes.

Comment: Yes, mabye that would work.. but I think this is the wrong path. From the beginning it looked easy, just get the action name and look up the method.. Mabye one could look at the mvc source, they need to look up the correct method.. :) .. It just becomes to much of a hack..